# Search JSON object in NodeJS

Tags: json, node.js

I have a json file which is shown below. I would like to search through the entire json object to find if the prechat_survey subject is "ttconnect id". how can this be done as chats.[prechat_survey].[subject] doesn't seem to work.   [image]

Comment: Please make your question clear. Cant able to understand, Post your expected code.

Comment: where is `ttconnect id` stored ? is it in the value field?

Answer (score 0):

You will need 2 loops to reach and iterate over the `prechat_survey` objects.

```
jsonObject.chats.forEach((obj)=>{
  obj.prechat_survey.forEach((o)=>{
    if(o.key=="Subject:" && o.value=="ttconnect id"){
      //do whatever you want to do
    }
  })
})
```